# What is the relationship between a characteristic polynomial/eigenvalues and image?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to determine the image of a matrix given just the characteristic polynomial?

[I now understand that for the kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590348/find-the-kernel-of-a-matrix-given-its-characteristic-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment9665754_4590348), the only way the equation to map to $0$ is if one of the roots was $0$ since $Av = \lambda v$.

But if the matrix isn't known, how can the image be known just given the eigenvalues? Ordinarily, with a given matrix, I would use the eigenvalues to find the eigenvectors through substitution and Gaussian Elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. We can't know the image of a matrix just with its eigenvalues. But we do get a some information of the image of a matrix from its eigenvalues. If a matrix $A : V\to V$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue, then the matrix is neither injective nor surjective. This tells us that the image is not $V$ but rather a proper subspace of $V$.

If all of the eigenvalues of the matrix are non-zero, then the matrix is injective, surjective and therefore invertible. This tells us that the image of the matrix is $V$.

Comment: You need $V=W$ for eigenvalues to make any sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for pointing that out. I was typing in a hurry and missed that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you elaborate on the meaning of W? In the problem I linked, I gave an example of p() = (3-)^5(5-)(^2+1). Since the eigenvalues are non-zero, it meets the second condition you've mentioned, but I'm still unclear about how they relate to W.

Comment: You meant to ask Seeker, not me. The $W$ that's left here is a typo that Seeker forgot to correct. The image is $V$ when the matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: @HikikiMe Fixed the typo.